# 16x2 LCD copper foil around the pin holes was accidentally removed

Tags: arduino, lcd, character-lcd

I tried to remove the I2C attached to the LCD. Is it okay if that copper foil around the 16x2 LCD pin holes got removed? I didn't do it intentionally, it just happened when I solder pumped the material. Is it significant for everything to work when I connect various pins? Thank you! I have attached a picture.

[image: This is what the pinhole looks like.]

Comment: It's only significant if you want to use that particular pin again.

Comment: The picture does not show which pin is it (meaning, the pin number) to know the function of it. So we can't say if that pin being broken is significant to you or if it limits you from doing what you want. You might also say in which mode or in which way you intend to use the display.

Comment: "remove the I2C attached to the LCD" What does this even mean?

Comment: The pins with the removed pads will not work again unless they are repaired. Be careful when working with PCBs.

Comment: @StarCat There is a good chance that pin is one of the data pins not needed in 4-bit mode, but because it is not sure how many pins (if any) is outside the cropped photo, there is no definite answer.

Comment: All is not lost. You still have some copper trace material you can solder a (very small) wire to it. Not easy but possible if necessary. Then after you better protect the join with some epoxy for it will be extra fragile.

Comment: Wow, this is pretty badly butchered. Big gouges across fine traces where the solder sucker slipped in a couple of places. Other plated holes may be damaged. It’s certainly repairable (assuming that pin is actually needed) but these things are not expensive. Maybe trash it.

Comment: The removed piece of foil is called a pad; this pad will not work since the copper is gone. Either you need this pad or you don't. If you do need it, it's still possible to repair it (with difficulty)